# SpagoBI : Setting up front page for user

Tags: spagobi

I want to set login landing page of normal user in SpagoBI. Like the page 'biuser' lands on specif [roject page instead of folder tree in left hand side pan

Answer (score 1):

Login via biadmin in server, go into menu configuration from Tools add a new node to 
main tree by 
left click on root node -> insert child Node,
make sure its at the top of HOME node (by moving up in order) and assign Document(report/cockpit) or a static html page for same, It also gives you the freedom to assign this screen to specific role.
now restart the program and login from the user you assigned that role.
DONE !!
for more 
http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/menu_definition